# What's the simplest way to list conflicted files in Git?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I just need a plain list of *conflicted* files.

Is there anything simpler than:

```
git ls-files -u  | cut -f 2 | sort -u
```

or:

```
git ls-files -u  | awk '{print $4}' | sort | uniq
```

I guess I could set up a handy `alias` for that, however was wondering how pros do it. I'd use it to write shell loops e.g. to auto-resolve conflict, etc. Maybe replace that loop by plugging into `mergetool.cmd`?

Comment: git status is enough

Comment: In conflicted merge  session` git merge --continue`  will show the list files with conflicts.

Comment: `git rebase --continue` didn't list the conflicts, just told me to fix them (git version 2.21.0)

Comment: none of this seems to work if the conflict marker is checked in

Answer (score 1608, accepted):

Use git diff, with [name-only](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---name-only) to show only the names, and [diff-filter=U](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203) to only include 'Unmerged' files (optionally, [relative](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---relativeltpathgt) to show paths relative to current working directory) .

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U --relative
```

Comment: I created an alias for this: `git config --global alias.conflicts "diff --name-only --diff-filter=U"`

Comment: @CharlesBailey, Am I missing something? What's *wrong* with `git status`?

Comment: @Pacerier, it's just messier. If you had a million unconflicting merges and one conflicting merge, you'd want something succinct for output.

Comment: @Jimothy how do you use that alias?

Comment: @sAguinaga: Simply run `git conflicts`

Comment: @QZSupport You must first set up the alias, as indicated in my earlier comment: `git config --global alias.conflicts "diff --name-only --diff-filter=U"`

Comment: @ChristianMatthew `diff-filter=U` asks to show only files that are unmerged, the option can use other options like `A` for added files, `M` for modified files and so on. See doc for more info: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203

Comment: This continues to show the file even after resolving the conflict. `git diff --check` works better.

Comment: It's worth noting that this only works when items haven't been staged (or unstaged) after arriving at the conflict. @cnlevy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49382772/2521092) (`git diff --check`) will find conflict markers for unstaged files.

Comment: @Pacerier nothing is wrong really. But there are situations, where you might want *only* the names of conflicting files. E.g. the command ```vim `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U` ``` will open all conflicting files in vim, so you can fix the conflicts one by one.

Comment: To disable pager in the git alias: `git config --global alias.conflicts "!git --no-pager diff --name-only --diff-filter=U"`

Comment: Such a basic functionality with a such a complex command. This is what is not fine with git.

Comment: This solution does not work if you are not `cd` into the root directory of the project. Better and easier is `git diff --check`

Answer (score 194):

`git diff --check`

will show the list of files containing conflict markers *including line numbers*.

For example:

```
> git diff --check
index-localhost.html:85: leftover conflict marker
index-localhost.html:87: leftover conflict marker
index-localhost.html:89: leftover conflict marker
index.html:85: leftover conflict marker
index.html:87: leftover conflict marker
index.html:89: leftover conflict marker
```

source : https://ardalis.com/detect-git-conflict-markers

Comment: I've found `git diff --check` telling me about other (less serious) problems too, like trailing whitespace, so a `git diff --check | grep -i conflict` might be in order for OP's case

Comment: `git diff --check` uses the whitespace rules from core.whitespace. You can disable all of the whitespace checks during `git` invocation to just get conflict markers: `git -c core.whitespace=-trailing-space,-space-before-tab,-indent-with-non-tab,-tab-in-indent,-cr-at-eol diff --check`

Comment: nice! it also shows stuff like trailing ws <3

Comment: `git diff --check` returns empty even `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U` returns files is it normal?

Comment: this doesn't work for committed code. not useful to pipelines where code is checked in

Comment: This is the best solution by far

Comment: `git diff --check` produces no output for me.  What does that mean?   `git status` shows three files modified.   I also get a message saying that I have a `merge conflict`.  i am trying to list the merge conflicts, but shows nothing.

Comment: @AgilePro it means there are no git conflit markers (like <<<<<<<, =======, and >>>>>>) in your files. You probably already deleted the markers from your files.

Comment: @cnlevy thanks for clarification.  Git still disallows pulls and merges because somewhere else there is a marker saying there are merge conflicts.  I guess I was expecting a function that would tell me WHY it is claiming there are merge conflicts when there actually are none.

Comment: This does not work for conflicted binaries

Answer (score 52):

Here is a fool-proof way:

```
grep -H -r "<<<<<<< HEAD" /path/to/project/dir
```

Comment: No. Git's index will still internally mark certain files as being in conflict even after the textual markers in the files are removed.

Comment: Alongside Alexander's comment, it's still useful to see this as an option :) Please don't delete.

Comment: Or to run within current working dir use a dot for path - `grep -H -r "<<<<<<< HEAD" .`

Comment: Hehe, this is my way of doing it too. Adding a `c` nicely results the count of conflicts too! One note is that I'd use flags `-Hrn` this will also supply line number information.

Comment: If you're using regex, I'd suggest `[<=>]{7}` instead of this. (Might need `-E` flag for that to work in grep.) Or, `<{7}` if you're not worried about dangling merge markers or want to count the conflicts. (You can also use `git grep` - then you don't need the `-r` flag.)

Comment: The `H` Flag means that the file name will be shown. `r` means recursive, If you do `git grep`, you put `--files-with-matches` instead of the `H` flag.

Comment: It's much faster to use git's grep command for large codebases because it will follow the rules configured in the .gitignore file. `git grep -H -r "<<<<<< HEAD"`

Comment: For `git stash apply`, `<< HEAD` will not be there. Instead `<< Updated Upstream

Comment: If you're IN your git dir, use `grep -Hrn "<<<<<<< " "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"`, and it will search from the root of your project

Answer (score 43):

Trying to answer my question:

No, there doesn't seem to be any simpler way than the one in the question, out of box.

After typing that in too many times, just pasted the shorter one into an executable file named 'git-conflicts', made accessible to git, now I can just:
`git conflicts` to get the list I wanted.

Update: as Richard suggests, you can set up an git alias, as alternative to the executable

```
git config --global alias.conflicts '!git ls-files -u | cut -f 2 | sort -u'
```

An advantage of using the executable over the alias is that you can share that script with team members (in a bin dir part of the repo).

Comment: I felt the same at that point - thinking how the hell people don't need this, and seeing how trivial it was to workaround. However, I've been using git for 2 years now and honestly haven't run into that "limitation" once more. So maybe that's not that much of common usecase after all?

Comment: This is simple enough that you could set up an alias for it `git config --global alias.conflicts "!git ls-files -u | cut -f 2 | sort -u"` (the ! means run this shell command, rather than just a git command).

Comment: Worth mentioning that you actually want 'single-quotes' instead of "double-quotes."  Otherwise, the `!` will be interpreted by your shell: `git config --global alias.conflicts '!git ls-files -u | cut -f 2 | sort -u'`

Answer (score 29):

`git status` displays "both modified" next to files that have conflicts instead of "modified" or "new file", etc

Comment: That's true. However this particular question was about a plain list of conflicted files.. this might be an XY problem (I can't remember why I actually needed that conflict list, but the fact that I haven't needed it since might suggest that I should have followed a different approach back then. Not sure now.. I also was writing scripts for autoresolving java-import conflicts which needed this list, ie. non-interactive use)..

Comment: Oh, I hadn't understood that. I thought you wanted a "normal" list for "normal" use. Which is why I freaked out with your own code and your self-answer... then I realized the "both modified" thingy worked for me (and I assumed you just wanted the same as me, why shouldn't you? ;-P ) Thanks for the upvote though :)

Comment: There can also be merge conflicts where one branch deleted a file and the other modified it. These won't show up with `git status | grep "both modified"`.

Answer (score 23):

```
git status --short | grep "^UU "
```

Comment: Note: You may need to search for ^UA and ^UD also, so the following pattern is more complete: "^U[UAD] "

Comment: or just `^U` to get everything starting with U

Comment: This isn't sufficient.  Conflicting files can have the following combinations: `DD, AU, UD, UA, DU, AA, UU`

Comment: @AnthonySottile: Can you explain the scenarios?  I posted what worked for my case.

Comment: @mda One example: Conflict where upstream modified, I deleted will have status `DU`

Comment: @AnthonySottile, Am I missing something? Why even bother with `grep` in the first place?

Comment: My usecase was supporting older versions of git (I believe <1.5) which do not have the `--diff-filter` option.

Comment: @AnthonySottile, are all those combinations _guaranteed_ to be conflicted, or are some of them just "possibly" conflicted? **Edit:** The chart at Mateusz's link seems to indicate that they are guaranteed to be conflicts.

Comment: I don't know if it's the _shortest_ regex, but this gets all the conflicted combinations and none of the unconflicted combinations: `grep -E "^([AUD][AU]|[UD]D) "`. See https://regex101.com/r/Wh1fUi/1

Comment: @self Also `^(.U|U.|AA|DD)`.

Answer (score 18):

This works for me:

`git grep '<<<<<<< HEAD'`

or

`git grep '<<<<<<< HEAD' | less -N`

Comment: Conflicts can include modified vs. deleted files which this solution will not cover.

Answer (score 16):

you may hit `git ls-files -u` on your command line it lists down files with conflicts

Answer (score 6):

I would also suggest the following command if you are working on a local git repository or in a directory in which `patch -p1 --merge < ...` was applied.

```sh
grep -rnw . -e '^<<<<<<<$'
```

Comment: This can be an ok solution, but really slows down with bigger projects.

Comment: I'm using git alias : `cf = "! bash -c 'grep --color=always -rnw \"^<<<<<<< HEAD$\"'"`

Answer (score 5):

If you attempt to commit, and if there are conflicts, then git will give you the list of the currently unresolved conflicts... but not as a plain list. This is usually what you want when working interactively because the list gets shorter as you fix the conflicts.

Comment: "interactively because the list gets shorter as you fix the conflicts." Interesting. I've always used mergetool for that purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this has been added to Git, but the files that have yet to be resolved are listed in the status message (git status) like this:

```
#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#   both modified:      syssw/target/libs/makefile
#
```

Note that this is the Unmerged paths section.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know where your git root directory, ${GIT_ROOT}, is, you can do,

```
 cat ${GIT_ROOT}/.git/MERGE_MSG | sed '1,/Conflicts/d'
```

Answer (score 1):

I've always just used `git status`.

can add `awk` at the end to get just the file names

`git status -s | grep ^U | awk '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 1):

slight variation of Charles Bailey's answer that gives more information:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | xargs git status
```

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents here (even when there are a lot of cool/working responses)

I created this alias in my `.gitconfig`

```
[alias]
 ...
 conflicts = !git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | grep -oE '[^/ ]+$'
```

which is going to show me just the names of the files with conflicts... not their whole path :)

Comment: +1 for using an alias, but this removes the file paths (keeping only the basename) which makes piping to other programs (like `git conflicts | xargs code` impossible. should just drop the grep, like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21541490/2788187

Comment: Good idea to create an alias. Just an info for others, to run alias you need to prefix git like this `git <alias>`. So in this case it would be `git conflicts`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use to a list modified files suitable for command line substitution in bash

```
git diff --numstat -b -w | grep ^[1-9] | cut -f 3
```

To edit the list use `$(cmd)` substitution.

```
vi $(git diff --numstat -b -w | grep ^[1-9] | cut -f 3)
```

Doesn't work if the file names have spaces.   I tried to use `sed` to escape or quote the spaces and the output list looked right, but the `$()` substitution still did not behave as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Utility git wizard https://github.com/makelinux/git-wizard counts separately unresolved conflicted changes (collisions) and unmerged files. Conflicts must be resolved manually or with mergetool. Resolved unmerged changes can me added and committed usually with git rebase --continue.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Jones Agyemang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20610258/802469) is probably sufficient for most use cases and was a great starting point for my solution. For scripting in [Git Bent](https://github.com/Taeluf/Git-Bent/), the git wrapper library I made, I needed something a bit more robust. I'm posting the prototype I've written which is not yet totally script-friendly

#### Notes

- The linked answer checks for `<<<<<<< HEAD` which doesn't work for merge conflicts from using `git stash apply` which has `<<<<<<< Updated Upstream`
- My solution confirms the presence of `=======` & `>>>>>>>`
- The linked answer is surely more performant, as it doesn't have to do as much
- My solution does NOT provide line numbers

#### Print files with merge conflicts

You need the `str_split_line` function from below.

```sh
# Root git directory
dir="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
# Put the grep output into an array (see below)
str_split_line "$(grep -r "^<<<<<<< " "${dir})" files
bn="$(basename "${dir}")"
for i in "${files[@]}"; do 
    # Remove the matched string, so we're left with the file name  
    file="$(sed -e "s/:<<<<<<< .*//" <<< "${i}")"

    # Remove the path, keep the project dir's name  
    fileShort="${file#"${dir}"}"
    fileShort="${bn}${fileShort}"

    # Confirm merge divider & closer are present
    c1=$(grep -c "^=======" "${file}")
    c2=$(grep -c "^>>>>>>> " "${file}")
    if [[ c1 -gt 0 && c2 -gt 0 ]]; then
        echo "${fileShort} has a merge conflict"
    fi
done
```

#### Output

```
projectdir/file-name
projectdir/subdir/file-name
```

#### Split strings by line function

You can just copy the block of code if you don't want this as a separate function

```sh
function str_split_line(){
# for IFS, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831429/when-setting-ifs-to-split-on-newlines-why-is-it-necessary-to-include-a-backspac
IFS="
"
    declare -n lines=$2
    while read line; do
        lines+=("${line}")
    done <<< "${1}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the accepted answer didn't work. To prevent from capturing

warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in [].
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory

In Powershell I used this instead:

```
git ls-files -u| ForEach{($_.Split("`t"))|Select-Object -Last 1}| get-unique
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```bash
$ git status | grep both
```

a sample output would be:

```
    both modified:   package.json
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine:

```
git status --porcelain=2 | grep ^u | awk '{ print $11 }'
```

In the porcelain format v2, a line for an unmerged paths starts with a "u". It's also designed to never change with a new version, so it's suitable for a script.

Answer (score -1):

Git marks conflicts in a file using "conflict markers", which IDEs like VS Code use to visually highlight the conflicts:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD 
original code
======= 
merged code
>>>>>>> merged_branch
```

You can find all files that still have conflict markers (i.e. all files you've yet to resolve conflicts for) using:

```
git diff --check | grep -i "conflict"
```

Comment: git: 'check' is not a git command.

Comment: I remove the downvote since you actually care about the post quality and improve it. But still, I wonder, how does this answer add to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49382772/4125622

Comment: @Phil You only need to look at the first comment on that answer for an answer to your question - this answer gets rid of the noise of a normal `git diff --check` and shows only the conflicts.

Answer (score -2):

Just read man page for git status, and filter what is needed.

```
 git status --help
```

Snippet:

```
       For paths with merge conflicts, X and Y show the modification states of each side of the merge. For paths that do not have merge conflicts, X shows the status of the index, and Y shows the status of the work tree. For untracked
   paths, XY are ??. Other status codes can be interpreted as follows:

   •   ' ' = unmodified

   •   M = modified

   •   A = added

   •   D = deleted

   •   R = renamed

   •   C = copied

   •   U = updated but unmerged

   Ignored files are not listed, unless --ignored option is in effect, in which case XY are !!.

       X          Y     Meaning
       -------------------------------------------------
                [AMD]   not updated
       M        [ MD]   updated in index
       A        [ MD]   added to index
       D                deleted from index
       R        [ MD]   renamed in index
       C        [ MD]   copied in index
       [MARC]           index and work tree matches
       [ MARC]     M    work tree changed since index
       [ MARC]     D    deleted in work tree
       [ D]        R    renamed in work tree
       [ D]        C    copied in work tree
       -------------------------------------------------
       D           D    unmerged, both deleted
       A           U    unmerged, added by us
       U           D    unmerged, deleted by them
       U           A    unmerged, added by them
       D           U    unmerged, deleted by us
       A           A    unmerged, both added
       U           U    unmerged, both modified
       -------------------------------------------------
       ?           ?    untracked
       !           !    ignored
       -------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score -3):

As highlighted in other answer(s) we can simply use command **git status** and then look for files listed under Unmerged paths: