# How to overcome git merge history ambiguity/obfuscation with '--ours'?

Tags: git, merge, revision-history

I am wondering if there any tools for providing a more verbose file history, especially with regard to merges where `our` changes are kept. This problem is best explained with an example.

Let's say I made a conflicting change on `master` and a `feature` branch:

```
git checkout master
<made some change to file.txt>
git commit -a -m "Change on master"
git checkout -b feature
<made conflicting change to file.txt>
git commit -a -m "Change on feature"
```

If I merge `feature` into `master` and keep my changes using `git checkout --ours file.txt` I get different results for `file.txt` than if I were to merge `master` into `feature` (and then merge `feature` into `master` to fast forward `master`). (I understand merging `--ours` effectively could have also been done inadvertently with `mergetool`.)

Using `git log -p` in both these scenarios, the merge commits do not report any change in `file.txt`, but its contents are different between the scenarios. Now `file.txt`'s change history has been obfuscated and it has become difficult to know which version is in `master`. I can run `git log -- file.txt`, but this solution doesn't scale and requires you already know what files were part of the bad merge.

If someone makes the wrong merge decision, if becomes difficult to track down which files were kept the same. Otherwise, if a merge made changes to a file, it is easy to see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the conflicts are getting resolved, they're just getting resolved incorrectly (per your comments on this answer), one way to see the differences in `file.txt` between two branches is with `git diff`:

```
git diff master feature -- file.txt
```

If you issue `git diff master feature` without any file specification, you'll see all the differences in all the repo's files. Creative applications of `git diff` will allow you to isolate nearly any changes you'd like.

Otherwise your best bet might be the merge commit itself. By default the commit message will output a conflicts section, which I'd advise against deleting.

Comment: If someone else uses `git mergetool` and opts to keeps their local changes for each conflict, the result is the same. I used `git checkout --ours <file>` to replicate (and better describe) the problematic behavior.

Comment: @Slythfox Changed my answer pretty much completely. Didn't realize you were using that command to repro it.

Comment: I haven't had the chance to play with this yet. Previously, I found the bad merge commit, re-merged, and then used [git ls-files -u](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065650/whats-the-simplest-way-to-git-a-list-of-conflicted-files) to get a list of conflicting files, and compared it against the bad merge to get an idea of what files were conflicted but kept as "ours." It seems to work, kinda. I also played with `git checkout --patch <revision> <file>` to get an idea of what changed between the bad merge and a known good commit, which seems like the same idea as `git diff`.

Comment: @Slythfox It's more or less the same idea, yeah.