# Git: see list of conflicts?

Tags: git

So I am trying to rebase and get conflicts. The git rebase command does list them, but is there any way for me to see the list of conflicts later with a separate git command, without continuing or skipping the rebase?

(I am writing a script to automate rebasing in favor of one branch or the other, without having to fire up an editor for every file. But grepping through the entire repo for >>>>>> and <<<<<< is rather time-consuming so I'd rather access the list directly)

Comment: Would `git status` do?

Comment: `git diff` does the job. Pass `-U0` flag to discard the text around the hunks.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff - search for `theirs`. (Sorry, I'm on Android and I hate typing on it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way to get a list of conflicted files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065650/whats-the-simplest-way-to-get-a-list-of-conflicted-files)

Answer (score 8):

Try with: `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U`

It should give you a plain list of the unmerged paths, like:

```
path/to/file
```

… whereas `git status` would show this:

```
Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
        both modified:   path/to/file
```

Answer (score 1):

This one usually what I use.
`git ls-files -u`

Comment: or something line this
`git ls-files -u  | cut -f 2 | sort -u`