# Git merge incoming changes for all remaining unmerged paths

Tags: git

I have an issue where I am merging in a branch that has produced over 50 files of merge conflicts. The only merge conflicts I was concerned about are the ones that affected the files I recently changed. I went and manually resolved and staged those files. Now 44 files remain. I would just like to accept incoming for all of them. Is there a way I can do that, either through git or vscode? Every solution i found online is resolving all or none, and vscode can only accept incoming conflicts for 1 file, not multiple files.

Answer (score 2):

You could fetch the list of remaining conflicting files with

```sh
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U
```

[Found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10874862/8559522).

Once you've got that you can just checkout each of them from the branch being merged in.

```sh
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | xargs git checkout --theirs --
```

Your working tree will now have only the changes from the branch you're merging in so you can just stage and commit everything.

Comment: Use `--theirs` for `<branch-being-merged-in>`, but the general principle is good. Upvoted.

Comment: That's great, I didn't realise `checkout` was aware of merges like that.

Comment: Yeah, very handy to have it available, along with `--ours` (or `-m` to restore the conflicted state if needed)